# How to add cocos2d-x to BlackBerry 10 project?

Tags: cocos2d-x, blackberry-10, blackberry-qnx

I want to create a simple game for BlackBerry 10 and I want to use cocos2d-x as a game engine. I compiled and ran examples from cosos-2d-x on simulator and it works fine. But problem is when I create *new project* and reference to cocos2d-x project. During building new project linker couldn't find some header files. **How to set up cocos2d-x to Blackberry 10 project?**

How I did it so far?

1. Unzipped cocos2d-x-2.1.4.zip
2. In QNX Momentics IDE I chose File->Import->General->Existing Projects into Workspace
3. In Import window I selected root directory (where I unzipped cocos2d-x) and selected Box2D, chipmunk, cocos2dx, CocosDenshion, extensions, HelloCpp, SimpleGame, TestCpp (all for Blackberry) and pressed Finish button. I didn't change default options in Import window.
4. I created New BlackBerry Project and in Properties of new project in Project References I selected Box2D, chipmunk, cocos2dx, CocosDenshion and extensions.
5. To new project I pasted code from HelloCpp for bulid test.

After that I received build errors. Should I set up Path and Symbols in Properties of project?

Thanks for the reply.

Rafal

Comment: Do the sample apps (HelloCpp etc) compile and run successfully?

Comment: I have exact same problem, maybe your problem is that you must uncheck the "Copy projects to workspace" option, in that should compile, but for me still failed... I don't know what to do, the newest version of cocos2d-x seems to be not working well with the new QNX Momentics IDE. I tested with the BB NDK 10 and the one for tablet OS BB NSK 2.1, both unsuccessfully... if you manage to solve the problem, please post an answer

Comment: @donturner - yes, samples in cocos2d-x for BlackBerry works fine, but problem is to create a new project from scratch and reference to all libraries I listed above.

Comment: @nosmirck - still not working. I tried also compile BBTemplateProject but I got errors with undefined references in decode.h (WebPGetFeaturesInternal, WebPInitDecoderConfigInternal).

Comment: I found something releted to this problem: http://denvycom.com/blog/setting-up-cocos2d-for-blackberry-10-development/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Rafal and nosmirck,

I wrote the post on denvycom (http://denvycom.com/blog/setting-up-cocos2d-for-blackberry-10-development/) about setting up Cocos2dx for Blackberry. 
Basically, I imagine the WebPInitDecoder error is as a result of a missing or unreferenced code file were it has been defined. Like I mentioned in the post, commenting out these files made the BBTemplateProject build successfully and run on my BBz10. Thus far, I have had no trouble using the  BBTemplateProject (with the commented files) as a base for my preliminary projects .

Did commenting the files out solve your compile errors ?

Comment: Thanks, this helped, although it is not a real solution for the problem because we should be able to link the missing libraries, but I think they are not really needed and commenting the callbacks is a simple solution. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. 
I have run into another Cocos2d Blackberry 10 related problem ... happy to have your thoughts and help on the matter ..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878599/how-to-import-and-use-qobject-in-a-bb10-cocos2d-based-app

Thanks